# Is every $ [[9,1,3]] $ CSS code a surface code?

Tags: stabilizer-code, surface-code

The paper [Projective Plane and Planar Quantum Codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810055) lists three non-equivalent $ [[9,1,3]] $ CSS codes coming from different cellulations of the projective plane (Figures 2, 3 and 4). The code from Figure 4 is the Shor code.

In the answer here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27699/19675 Adam Zalcman lists yet another $ [[9,1,3]] $ surface code with explicit stabilizer  generators given in the comments.

Is it possible that all $ [[9,1,3]] $ CSS codes are surface codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is too trivial, but take the $[[7,1,3]]$ code and add two dummy qubits.

Comment: Can you explain for which cellulation of which surface this is a surface code?

Comment: Hmm I think the original question asked “ Is every [[9,1,3]] CSS code a surface code?” to which the above is a (trivial) counter example.

Comment: I see. Could you explain more about why adding two dummy qubits to the $ [[7,1,3]] $ code cannot be a surface code? That claim seems plausible but I'm just not very familiar with techniques for showing that a given CSS code cannot be any surface code. Even if you don't have a totally formal proof, I would just be curious to hear any partial proof/approaches you might suggest to showing that the [[7,1,3]] code plus 2 dummy qubits is not a surface code. If you think it's better I can make a separate question "Proof that Steane 7 qubit code is not equivalent to any surface code"

Comment: follow-up asking if Steane code is a surface code https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32998/is-the-7-1-3-steane-code-a-surface-code?rq=1