# Is the $[\![7,1,3]\!]$ Steane code a surface code?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, surface-code

All surface codes are CSS codes.

The smallest error correcting ($ d=3 $) CSS code is for 7 qubits. So we can be sure that the $ [\![5,1,3]\!] $ code is not equivalent to a surface code since no surface code, in fact not even any CSS code, exists with parameters $ [\![5,1,3]\!] $.

What about the $ [\![7,1,3]\!] $ Steane code? Is the Steane code equivalent to some surface code? In [Projective Plane and Planar Quantum Codes](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810055) it is claimed that the Steane code cannot be equivalent to any surface code on $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ since there is no cellulation of $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ with $ 7 $ edges and the lengths of all essential cycles and dual cycles at least 3. What about surface codes on other surfaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A surface code is defined by a planar graph, embedded on a plane (that's the "surface" part), where edges (E) are qubits, Z checks are faces (F), and X checks are vertices (V).

All connected planar graphs embedded on the plane have [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) V-E+F=+2.

The Steane code has 3 X checks, 3 Z checks, and 7 qubits. Computing the implied characteristic we get V-E+F = 3-7+3 = -1 != +2. Therefore the Steane code is not a surface code. At least, not one embedded on a flat surface.

Comment: In principle there could still be an embedding by adding redundant checks. Take the toric code with n=3 (18 qubits, 9 X checks, 9 Z checks) : 9 - 18 + 9 = 0 which is euler characteristic of torus.  The 9 checks have a redundant one; without it the characteristic is -2. So adding two redundant X and Z checks to the steane code could in principle change things

Comment: Is it possible that the Steane code is a surface code on a genus 2 surface (which as you point out would have Euler characteristic $ -2=\chi=2-2g $)

Answer (score 2):

If it helps, the Steane code is known to be equivalent to a color code, not a surface code. See here for example-  https://earltcampbell.com/2016/09/26/the-smallest-interesting-colour-code/,
or here- https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/steane

However, see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02065 about the similarities between color and surface codes.